# Bluetooth Chat Sample from Android SDK compiled --> BluetoothChat.apk. Is there any Incompatibility?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am just testing Bluetooth Chat sample SDK from 
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html. It works fine in some android phones (of course, 2.1 or higher), but I found problems about synchronization or connection between any models. Apperars missages like: "Unable to connect device" or something like that: "An error occured while synchronizing":

Samsung Galaxy S (2.2.1) <----> Samsung Galaxy S (2.2.1). OK.

Samsung Galaxy S (2.2.1) <----> Samsung Galaxy 3 (2.2.1). OK.

Samsung Galaxy S (2.2.1) (SERVER) ----> HTC Tatoo (2.2.1) (CLIENT) OK.

HTC Tatoo (2.2.1) (SERVER) ----> Samsung Galaxy S (2.2.1) (CLIENT) Unable to connect device

Samsung Galaxy S (2.2.1) <----> HTC Wildfire (2.2.1). Synchro error.

The app was downloded from android-sdk and compiled in Eclipse Helios obtaining BluetoothChat.apk file. Then It was installed to these phones above indicated. I thought this app must be compatible with any phone with bluetooth and android 2.1 O.S. or higher. May I be wrong?

Any idea it would be grateful.

Thank you.

EDITED:

Samsung Galaxy S (2.2.1) (SERVER)----> HTC Wildfire (2.2.1) (CLIENT). OK
It's impossible to pair from BluetoothChat app. Then, I have paired them from O.S. Wilsfire. Adjusts --> Wireless and Nets Connections --> Bluetooth Adjusts ---> Search devices. Now I can connect and chat with them from BluetoothChat app if the Galaxy S tries to connect to HTC Wildfire. Otherwise there is not success.

EDITED 15/04/2011:

Samsung Galaxy S (2.2.1) ----> HTC Tatoo (2.2.1). OK

As HTC Wildfire, only it is possible if Galaxy S tries connect to Tatoo.

It is true that sometimes I can connect at first time and sometimes at second, third time and even never. Then I have to unpair from Ajusts, Wireless, Bluetooth Adjusts and then turn back to pair. It' s very strange.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely sounds like compatibility issues - which is rather sad.
The problem is that many device makers change the underlying bluetooth from BlueZ to other stacks and that breaks the APIs or their behavior.
Its impossible to find what (and if any) changes the devices makes on the android software under the hood

Comment: You are right. Then, which is the right way? I found some incompatibilities on HTC Wildfire and HTC HD2, both with android 2.1 or higher. Should I make my own stack for these devices? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have had reported issues getting a game I wrote to connect reliably via bluetooth using that code as a base.  The most reliable voodoo dance i had to get different phones to connect was via the following:

```
1) Both players startup activity that has the Bluetooth functionality
```

`1a) If the devices have never been paired, one player should use the context menu hardbutton in Bluetooth Game and set their device discoverable`

```
    2)The other player should then use the context menu hard button in 
Bluetooth Game and select Connect a device, then select the other phone 
from the discovered device list.  The game will start automatically at that point.

**Do not have the phones pre-paired before starting bluetooth game.**
```

I hope I didn't change my code base so far from the example this doesn't make any sense in your context.. It was about a year and 1/2 ago....

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your comment. Although It could became useful

Answer (score 0):

I've found that on different devices with the same android version bluetooth works differently. As of Bluetooth Chat, it worked always for me with Motorola Droid and Samsung Galaxy, but sometimes threw a "serversocket closed" or similar exception with HTC Hero (in pair with Droid or Galaxy). I searched this problem on SOF and found that alot of people complain about bad bluetooth support on HTC phones.

Comment: I thought it too, but rigth now I have an app installed in a Galaxy S and in a HTC Wildfire, that works fine in both phones. This app use Bluettoth to comunicate with a device (diagnostic tool). By the moment I don't know that Bluetooth service they use... Thank you.

Comment: Yes, Wildfire-Desire's BT is less buggy then Hero's one

Comment: Then, Could a ROM arrange this issue?